# is there a jpg viewer that shows pictures as full screen?

Tags: windows, jpeg

is there a jpg viewer that shows pictures as full screen ?

Comment: Uhhh... I'm having a hard time thinking of a single image viewer that *doesn't* offer a full screen view option... Including the built-in Windows one... Are you looking for a specific feature within it?

Comment: If it's just in the slideshow - you can’t zoom or show it in fill mode. Our Penteract Picture Viewer (for Windows 10) can default to fullscreen+fill so you use all of your screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the built in Picture and Fax Viewer.

Right click over the image and select **Preview** (if it's bold then it's the default action so double-clicking will do the same thing.

Then click the slide show icon (screen) or press F11 to start the slide show.

Esc takes you out.

You can download 3rd party programs that do this as well which might have more configuration options. One such is:

http://www.4neurons.com/other/FPV/

Comment: "Pausing" the Windows Photo Viewer slide show (to view a single image fullscreen) is not immediately obvious. Ashamed to admit it took me a minute to figure this out, but maybe it will help someone else: in the default Windows Photo Viewer slide show, right click on the photo and select "Pause" in the dropdown.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work properly on hi-res displays with scaling. In Windows 10 the best I can do is to use the Photos app, enable tablet mode to hide the title bar, and go into taskbar properties to auto-hide the taskbar. Still get annoying left/right arrows popping up. Come on Microsoft, how difficult is a simple full-screen photo viewer that just works?

Answer (score 5):

Vote for [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), freeware, great photo viewer and some minor image editing as well.

Comment: also allows multiple instances to be opened on multiple monitor setups.

Comment: Last time I used IrfanView (a few months ago) it required admin privileges and made it possible to see images and slideshow history across multiple user accounts - a big security hole.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use windows Built in **Picture and Fax Viewer.** . You can go to full screen mode when clicked on **Slide Show**  But disadvantage is that it automatically changes images if found in the current directory unless paused
- **Inzomia image viewer** enables you to see a single image in full-screen . I found it  [here](http://izview.com/viewer_-features/fullscreen-image-viewer/) . But the software is not free